# Do there exist $n^2$ real coefficients such that all matrices in $\Bbb R^{n∗n}$ containing those coefficients are invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Do there exist $n^2$ real coefficients such that all matrices in $\Bbb R^{n∗n}$ containing those coefficients (for any permutations) are invertible? Can we take these coefficients to be in $[1,2]$ ?

Comment: Can you clarify what "containing those coefficients" means? Do you mean that the coefficients of the matrix are some permutation of your list? If so, you can take your list to be any set of algebraically independent real numbers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're trying to find $a = (a_{11}, \dots, a_{nn})\in \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ such that the function
\begin{align*}
f(a) &= \det \begin{pmatrix}a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ a_{n1} & \cdots & a_{nn}\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
has $f(ga)\not = 0$ for every permutation $g\in S_{n^2}$. Each $f(ga)$ is a polynomial in the $a_{ij}$ and thus is nonzero almost everywhere. Thus almost all $a$ satisfy your condition, and in particular you can choose a point in $[1, 2]^{n^2}$.